# Listing Pods with name and field selector

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I need to list down all the pods with status complete and with given name.

```
user@host:~$ kubectl get pods
NAME                             READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
App1-something                    1/1       Running   570        2d
App2-something                    1/1       completed 597        2d
App3-something                    1/1       completed 570        2d
App4-something                    1/1       Running   597        2d
```

Using Field Selector i can list completed pods, but not able to find the correct command to list down required pod with specific name

Something to get below output

```
App3-something                    1/1       completed 570        2d
```

**kubectl get pod --field-selector=status.phase==Succeeded** and pod name is App3-something

Answer (score 5):

You can use comma to add multiple conditions like `--field-selector=metadata.name=app3-something,,status.phase=Succeeded`.

```
kubectl get pod --field-selector=metadata.name=App3-something,status.phase=Completed
```

Reference: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/field-selectors/

--

```
C:\>kubectl get pods
NAME             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
app1-something   1/1     Running   0          62s
app2-something   1/1     Running   0          56s
app3-something   1/1     Running   0          52s

C:\>kubectl get pod --field-selector=metadata.name=app3-something,,status.phase=Running
NAME             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
app3-something   1/1     Running   0          57s
```

Comment: i need pods with completed state only, not in running state.

Comment: Updated the answer, you can use comma to add multiple conditions

Comment: Thanks for your update, it solves problem in half, i still have to write command like this, kubectl get pod --field-selector=status.phase==Succeeded,metadata.name=App3-something-4l2x, i want to avoid writing suffix 412x as get command will be part of automation, and i cant put same, i am looking for something like ( name starts with App3)

Answer (score 1):

Use `grep` on the output of the `kubectl` command:

```
kubectl get pod --field-selector=status.phase==Succeeded | grep -n 'App3-something'
```

Comment: is there any other way if i can filter same, On Windows PShell it will not work, something it can work with both platforms

Comment: Does `kubectl get pod <podName> --field-selector=status.phase==Succeeded` solve the purpose?

Comment: actually I don't understand the problem statement now that I think of it. You say you need to `list down all the pods with status complete and with given name` if the pod name is already given there will only a single pod with that name.

Comment: it solves, but keeping in mind there can be multiple pods which i need to list ( For e.g starting with same name with different suffix.  (App3-2cxxsxs34 and App3-233xsdce4)

Comment: but they are all different pods, may be you meant all completed pods for a given job or something?

Comment: i didn't use label till now ( was thinking of ), my use case is this, it is a k8s job, and jobs sets up one pod and that pod in turns create another pod so ( 1 job, 2 pods ) and i need to list, get or delete only those pods once they get completed ( However both pods starts with same name ) something like pod name starts with App3 should work

Comment: You can use this field `ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 100` to auto-deleted completed jobs if that's what you want.

Comment: No! , i want to jeep that job for logs, untill next run, this wont work in my use-case

Comment: @Zester07 You get the names of the Pods associated with your Job by checking the Events section of `kubectl describe job $JOB`. Than you can list, get or delete them.

Answer (score 1):

get "completed" pods

```
oc get pods --field-selector=status.phase=Succeeded
```

get "error" pods

```
oc get pods --field-selector=status.phase=Failed
```